# Is it possible to use google analytics in server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a URLShortener application and I want to use `Google Analytics` for shorted urls. But I use `Response.Redirect()` method and I can't use local script of google analytics.

I want to know is it possible to have something like google analytics script in server and run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework](http://msaf.codeplex.com/) which also supports Google Analytics.

I would assume that they do this in C# code, which *should* be adaptable to be used inside server-side code, too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use google analytics in server. You need to have a Google Analytics account, [as explained here](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009694).

After setting up your account they will give you a unique tracking code along with a javascript code which you have to put in your website or master page which you want to track. This javascript code will do all magic for you and you can watch this information from your GA account.

You can even integrate this chart with your website, using the Google chart facility through
Google Analytics Easy Dashboard Javascript Library ([more information here](http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/reporting/javascript/ez-ga-dash/docs/user-documentation.html)).

From this tutorial you can setup your website to catch GA data into your site and display in your own webpage through Google charts.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's technically possible.  All GA does is set some variables and makes an HTTP request to the GA server, which can be done with JS or by grabbing a gif from the server.

The main issue is that you won't get a lot of the data that you would expect like browser, location, OS version, etc. because the client making the request would be your own server.

It would probably be best to add some event tracking data to the redirected location and track that with GA event tracking, that way you could get a more accurate dataset.

If you do want to continue down the path of most resistance though, this is a pretty good write up of how you'd go about it.  http://automateeverything.tumblr.com/post/20500736298/google-analytics-without-javascript-or-cookies  It's not C# specific, but you should be able to abstract it.